# Jquery/Javascript/AJAX Dynamic Contact List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a dynamic contact list loading the contacts from my server without any HTML markup (short of the mark up made with JQuery or Javascript). I am also trying to add one person to the list at the start of my getContacts function and am not having anything come up, with or without my attempt to add this person.

I am new to using $.ajax and would greatly appreciate any help with this. Here is some of my code, I have a JSFiddle link showing all of my code.

```
function getContacts(url, type, dataType, firstname, lastname, phone) {
    function send() {
        var person = {
            firstname: "Crash",
            lastname: "Bandicoot",
            phone:"(123) 456-7890"
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: type,
        dataType: dataType,
        data: person,
        data: { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, phone: phone },
        success: showContacts(data)
    });
};

//== Main Entry ==//
$(document).ready(function () {
    getContacts("http://website/contacts", "get", "jsonp", "", "", "");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16mzq59r/embedded/result/

Comment: you are not using "send()" function, and firstname, lastname and phone are coming from nowhere

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have the contacts stored in a JSON at the URL and am trying to pull that data and display it. I have never used $.ajax() before and am not sure where to take this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what's the structure you are expeting in your web service? also, if you are using an GET ajax request, why are you passing data? if you are trying to save a new `person` you should use a POST

Comment: I'm trying to make an unordered list for each contact. The only information listed for each contact is {"firstname":"Name", "lastname":"Last", "phone":"number"} which I want to use as my list items for each list (contact).

Comment: if getContacts() is there to retrieve data, why are you creating a "send()" method? and why are you passing data in the ajax request?

Comment: also, your fiddle has no HTML (not even the `body` tag to bind in `showContacts`. It doesnt have references to jquery either, so you cant use $.ajax

Comment: I have removed the send method, it's not my focus right now. I have updated the fiddle here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/16mzq59r/3/embedded/result/)

The contact information is still not pulling from my JSON though, can you please help with that? I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: Is the ajax request being made? how is the returning data formatted?